# lite-serverbs-config.js: middleware and array of folders

Tags: browser-sync, lite-server

I had this bs-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    server: {
        middleware: {
            1: apiProxy
        }
    }
};
```

And this separate one:

```
module.exports = {
    server: [".", "dist"]
};
```

How can I join both configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
module.exports = {
    server: {
        middleware: {
            1: apiProxy,
        },

        baseDir: [".", "dist"]
    }
};
```